# Python Seasonality Detection

Tags: time-series, signals, detection

What is the best way to detect seasonality in a signal (time series) in Python? I want to provide the algorithm with the signal and the output should be a 1 indicating seasonality exists and 0 indicating it does not exist.

Comment: I would at scipy to see if there was not already a module to do that for you. 
A quick google search reveled these articles that might be helpful 
http://www.seanabu.com/2016/03/22/time-series-seasonal-ARIMA-model-in-python/

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162682/how-to-identify-the-seasonality-of-a-timeseries-from-the-periodogram

Answer (score 0):

Hope that helps for some basic usage, still I do not suggest it for complicated problems. A simple seasonality detection code I wrote:

```
def check_repetition(arr, limit, index_start, index_end):
    """
    Checks repetition in data so that we can apply de-noising.
    """
    length = index_start

    # length is the length we want to apply the checking
    # check how many periods there are with that kind of length
    for i in range(0, int( len(array)/length)):

        # if the difference in seasons is not smaller than the limit
        condition  = np.array( arr[i:int(i+length)]) - np.array( arr[int( i+length):int( i+2*length)])
        condition  = np.sum([abs(number) for number in condition])

        if condition >= limit :
            # check if the length is still bigger than the limit
            # increase the length to check 
            if length + 1 <= index_end:
                #print( "Checked for length:" + str( length))
                return check_repetition(arr, limit, length + 1, index_end)

            # if not than no more computations needed
            else:
                return 0

        # if it passed the for loop for one cycle of i then return the number of entries per cycle
        if i == int( len(array)/length)-2:
            return(length)

    # if nothing worked
    return 0
```

This returns the seasonality length. You can play with it in starting with seasonality from array length/2 to a small value, or the opposite. Also included is some noise detection with the parameter limit, which should limit the amount of noise accepted.